# Is there a math error in Bancor paper?

Tags: ram, exchange, bancor

According to Dan Larimer here https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3032 
"The Bancor Protocol math is wrong in their paper".

However I am reviewing the details here https://goo.gl/HXQBUr and it seems correct. (It is possible to reach the formulas in a simpler way without integrating). Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After considerable thought and discussions with other people, I affirm that there is no error in Rosenfeld's Bancor paper as Dan Larimer suggests.

Therefore, there seems to be no theoretical explanation (so far) for the *individual* formulas implemented in convert_to_exchange and convert_from_exchange at exchange_state.cpp (EOSIO Dawn 4.0). 
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/exchange_state.cpp

However the composition of *both* formulas, lead to the conversion between EOS and RAM in such a way that the product of the connectors reserves (EOS times RAM) is constant. This means exact agreement with Rosenfeld's paper (https://goo.gl/HXQBUr) section "multiple reserve currencies" taking S=S_0, m=2 and F_1=F_2.

Thank you @bytemaster for your answers, attention, everything.

Comment: These findings resulted from a collaboration with redjade and hyunwoongJi (EOS Seoul). See also: https://gist.github.com/redjade/ca88d90e3f838c57ea7a1a287b23e30a

Answer (score 5):

The forumula is ambiguous over "when" in time you read the balance (before or after). For all of my testing I was never able to get the paper's formula to work without giving profits to users.